# Validation on mobile number

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the logic when I want to validate one mobile number field i.e mobile no should be numeric,10 digits  as well as  not start from 0,1,2,3,4,5.??
I am using SQL Developer.

Thanks

Comment: I prefer to do it  using a function, is this numeric or char field ?

Comment: And have UPDATE/INSERT triggers to call that function.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Mobile number has varchar2 datatype , & I want to know the logic which can be use in if condition to compare.

Comment: In my phone book I have several numbers stored like `+1603....`, i.e. including country code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly dissuade you from storing the mobile number as a *number*.  Although you don't want leading zeros, that might change in the future.  Plus, the value is not really a number -- arithmetic is not defined on it.

So:

```
create table t (
    mobile_number varchar2(10),
    check (regexp_like(mobile_number, '^[6-9][0-9]{9}$')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use constraints. In your case, you want that the field is 10 digits and that it does not start with 0,1,2,3,4,5.

For complex formats is better to use regular expressions, but in your requirement is not needed.

```
SQL> create table t ( mobile number(10) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t add constraint chk_mob_phn check ( SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(mobile),1,1) not in ( 0,1,2,3,4,5) ) ;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t add constraint chk_mob_len check ( length(mobile) = 10 ) ;

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t values ( 0298338383 ) ;
insert into t values ( 0298338383 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS.CHK_MOB_PHN) violated

SQL>  insert into t values ( 99999 ) ;
 insert into t values ( 99999 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SYS.CHK_MOB_LEN) violated

SQL>  insert into t values ( 6987838322 ) ;

1 row created.
```